# Query regarding $\sup(cA)$ when $c<0$.

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

As part of a problem that I am solving, I am required to postulate a statement concerning $\sup (cA)$ where $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and $c<0$, having just before proved that $\sup (cA) = c\sup(A)$ when $c>0$.

But if we consider the set $A = \{x|x\leq a\}$ where $a\in\mathbb{R}^+$ then by definition $cA = \{cx|x\in A\}$ where $c<0$ but $cA$ is not bounded above and therefore has no supermum, So how can we postulate a general statement where it does not even make sense in this particular case?

**PS:** I forget to mention this before, but for all sets under consideration, we can only assume that they are bounded above.

Comment: What about the case $c=-1$?

Comment: My guess is that you are allowed to formulate a conjecture using something which is not the supremum... say, the infimum.

Comment: @Did Say $\inf (ca) = c\sup(A)$?

Comment: Why not? Now, the proof perhaps?

Comment: If $A$ is  not empty and $c<0$ then (1) If $A$ has a  lower bound in $\Bbb R$ then $\sup(cA)=c\inf (A).$ ...(2) If $A$ has no lower bound in $\Bbb R$ then $cA$ has no upper bound in $\Bbb R.$